# Refrence Error : local storage is not defined React js. after deploying on vercel

Tags: reactjs, vercel

Currently I deployed my mern project in which I have user profile section in local storage I am storing the data of username , email and in my userprofile section I am trying to get this username and email from local storage in my localhost:8080 it's working as expected but after deploying it's shows undefined plz help to resolve this issue

plz help to resolve this issue

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.